# Selected Index Changed return null values on a populated Grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I have a function that checks which sql query needs to be executed and return a DataTable, it is called searchData and is inside the CarsDataSet class

```
DataTable dataTable = null; //before there is code to detect the sql command to execute
    if (sqlCommand != null)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand, con);
        dataTable = new DataTable();
        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
    }

    return dataTable;
```

I am using then, this function on a aspx.cs page in order to bind this DataTable to a GridView..

```
GridViewCarsFiltered.DataSource = carsDataSet.searchData(type, manufacturer, maxPrice, minPrice, maxYear, minYear);
GridViewCarsFiltered.DataBind();
```

The GridView gets populated normally, but the problem comes when a try to get values of a row using an select index changed handler..

```
protected void GridViewCarsFiltered_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    string carId = GridViewCarsFiltered.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

I am receiving an **'ArgumentOutOfRangeException'** saying that carId is null.

This is my GridView, the DataSourceID is null because I am setting that from code behind..

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewCarsFiltered" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" DataSourceID="" ForeColor="Black" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridViewCarsFiltered_SelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyNames="Id">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="type" HeaderText="type" SortExpression="type" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="manufacturer" HeaderText="manufacturer" SortExpression="manufacturer" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="model " HeaderText="model " SortExpression="model " />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="colour" HeaderText="colour" SortExpression="colour" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="price" SortExpression="price" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="year" HeaderText="year" SortExpression="year" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="location" HeaderText="location" SortExpression="location" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="username" SortExpression="username" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And this is a screenshot of the actual populated GridView

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59mkV.png)

I hope I've been clear enough and that some of you can help me...
Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure that `Cells` at index `1` (making it the _second_ column) is being populated?

Comment: Yes it is, I have more cells populated which I did not upload with my code as not relevant. If I comment out code for first cell I will have the same problem to retrieve the second cell..already tried it!

Comment: can you try  GridViewRow row =GridViewCarsFiltered.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];     string carId=row.Cells[1].Text;

Comment: Same thing, not working. I have been using the same event handler in different forms and it works fine, it detects fields in the row correctly.

Comment: Can you post the markup of your GridView? The problem seems to come from `Cells[1]`, as suggested by @khlr.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way to retrieve a value in this kind of situation is to use `DataKeyNames` instead of getting the value from the cell itself. This method can also be used to get values from fields that are not displayed in the columns of the GridView.

You can add the `Id` field to that attribute in the markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Id" ... >
```

and retrieve the value in code-behind this way:

```
protected void gv_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    int carId = (int)gv.DataKeys[gv.SelectedRow.RowIndex].Values["Id"];
}
```

Note: I used `gv` instead of `GridViewCarsFiltered` only to reduce the width of the code samples.

**UPDATE**

On the other hand, if the GridView is empty after selecting the row, the problem could be that the ViewState is disabled (at the page level or in Web.config). Enabling it should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I am sorry to have not been clear enough. I've updated the details on my question. I've tried to follow your solution but I am having the same exception..

Comment: If you comment out your code in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler, is the GridView empty after selecting the row?

Comment: I commented out the code inside the 'SelectIndexChanged' handler and after selecting a row the GridView disappear. I've then enabled the ViewState in Web.config and still the same thing, getting same exception.

Comment: Search for "ViewState" in all files of the projet (or solution). It may be deactivated somewhere else (for example, in the `Page` directive at the top of the ASPX file).

Comment: I've been enabling the ViewState to these pages but still get the same error. It is possible that I am getting this error because of the way I populate the GridView?